# Getting data of Bootstrap table after AJAX refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to get data from Bootstrap table just after refreshing the table which is getting the data from AJAX request.

```
table.bootstrapTable('refresh');
var data = table.bootstrapTable('getData');
```

This gives me the data which was before calling an AJAX - I think it's because getData is called before refresh is fully completed. I've search for an event that triggers after refresh is done, but there's no one.

Getting it by value of DOM element gives me the same result.  Calling `delay()` is not the option at all. Do you have any idea how to do it?

The code is a bit complicated (in a few functions) but:

```
post.done(function(data) {
    //...some code
    table.bootstrapTable('refresh');
    $this.updateSomethingInTable(table);
})


updateSomethingInTable= function(detailsTable) {
    //...some code
   var detailsTableData = detailsTable.bootstrapTable('getData');
    //updating something with detailsTableData
}
```

Comment: You should use `load` instead `http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/load.html`

Comment: @Hackerman load that calls the function that triggers AJAX request and returns the data?

Comment: Can you add your ajax code too pls

Comment: @Hackerman sure

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

```
$('#table').on('load-success.bs.table', function() {
    // your code to get data
});
```

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events

I've test on testing on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/16571/

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. This event is fired, as said in the documentation: `after the click the refresh button`

Answer (score 0):

onPostBody
jQuery Event: post-body.bs.table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).